# window.onerror and try catch js

Tags: javascript, try-catch, onerror

I have a window.onerror defined in my project global
Also I have a method throwing an error
I am trying to catch the error in try catch block but from some reason it's not stop at the catch clause

```
window.onerror = (...) => {...}
const throwError = () => {throw new Error("")} 
try { throwError() } catch (e) { ... }
```

Comment: It does _go_ into catch statement (easy to check, just place log there or something). What it does afterwards depends on what's in your code.

Comment: I know it should but it doesn't maybe the problem is deeper then i described

Comment: My crystal ball says that you're throwing the error in an asynchronous callback. Yes, the problem is deeper than the snippet you posted here, please [edit] your question to include code that actually reproduces the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: you are right that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bergbi said -

> My crystal ball says that you're throwing the error in an asynchronous
>   callback. Yes, the problem is deeper than the snippet you posted here,
>   please edit your question to include code that actually reproduces the
>   unexpected behaviour. – Bergi Feb 15 at 12:16

And He was right that was the problem - I was able to walk around that by changing the async callback